# How do I sort jquery response by calculating attribute length and / or number of slashes present in descending order?

Tags: ansible

I have a jquery response that looks something like this:

```
{
    "id_hname_type": [
        {
            "hname": "Global/NETWORK/DATA CENTERS/PRIMARY DC",
            "id": "d8cf28e4-5955-4221-a6ba-b8c2c2a49647",
            "type": [
                "area"
            ]
        },
        {
            "hname": "Global/NETWORK/BRANCH SITES/NORTH EAST",
            "id": "c6843603-ab6f-4afb-9258-0f3d0f09b804",
            "type": [
                "area"
            ]
        },
        {
            "hname": "Global/NETWORK/BRANCH SITES",
            "id": "493381e5-9d71-42df-b3d5-79eefbf5b07f",
            "type": [
                "area"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to sort in descending order that list based on the the length of hname attribute and/or the number of the slashes present in that same attribute. After that I will extract the id an create id list following that same order but that I already know how to do.

This is what I have tried:

```
    - name: Sort the id_hname_type dictionary based on the number of slashes in hname
      set_fact:
        sorted_id_hname_type: "{{ id_hname_type | sort(attribute='hname' | regex_replace('/', '') | length, reverse=true) }}"
```

But always I always get error similar to this one:

> fatal: [dnac_server]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: dict object has no element 5. dict object has no element 5\n\nThe error appears to be in '/Users/andresfr/MyAnsible/dnac/MyPlaybooks/CSS/CSS_dnac_site_hierarchy_delete.yml': line 201, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name: Sort the id_hname_type dictionary based on the number of slashes in hname\n      ^ here\n"}

The expected output would be something like:

```
{
"sorted_id_hname_type": [       
   {
        "hname": "Global/FCMB NETWORK/DATA CENTERS/PRIMARY DC",
        "id": "d8cf28e4-5955-4221-a6ba-b8c2c2a49647",
        "type": [
            "area"
        ]
    },
    {
        "hname": "Global/FCMB NETWORK/BRANCH SITES/NORTH EAST",
        "id": "c6843603-ab6f-4afb-9258-0f3d0f09b804",
        "type": [
            "area"
        ]
    },
    {
        "hname": "Global/NETWORK/BRANCH SITES",
        "id": "493381e5-9d71-42df-b3d5-79eefbf5b07f",
        "type": [
            "area"
        ]
    },
    {
        "hname": "Global/NETWORK/DATA CENTERS",
        "id": "426e3c41-3245-4c5a-b742-e567ab3b7cff",
        "type": [
            "area"
        ]
    },
    {
        "hname": "Global/NETWORK",
        "id": "24db7872-91bf-4890-b535-92d069b75950",
        "type": [
            "area"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Could you please provide an example output you would like to have?

Comment: Hey @Khaled, I have edited my post to include example of expected output. Thanks

Comment: By the way, on that sample output, the contents of the listed are sorted in descending order taking into consideration the number of slashes present in the hname attribute (3, 2 and then 1).

Comment: Thanks both Vladimir Botka and @Khaled for your answers. Both did work, I tested both, and I liked that both used Ansible built-in features. Vladimir's answer achieved the goal with less code lines, and Khaled answer was very useful and more like a class. 
I found a third way using custom Python filter that I'll be sharing for reference. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. I had some thoughts about python, but preferred to do it only with ansible. Good luck 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the data for testing

```yaml
    id_hname_type:
      - hname: Global/NETWORK
        id: 24db7872-91bf-4890-b535-92d069b7595
        type: [area]
      - hname: Global/NETWORK/DATA CENTERS
        id: 426e3c41-3245-4c5a-b742-e567ab3b7cff
        type: [area]
      - hname: Global/NETWORK/DATA CENTERS/PRIMARY DC
        id: d8cf28e4-5955-4221-a6ba-b8c2c2a49647
        type: [area]
      - hname: Global/NETWORK/BRANCH SITES/NORTH EAST
        id: c6843603-ab6f-4afb-9258-0f3d0f09b804
        type: [area]
      - hname: Global/NETWORK/BRANCH SITES
        id: 493381e5-9d71-42df-b3d5-79eefbf5b07f
        type: [area]
```

Create *counters*

```yaml
  counters: "{{ id_hname_type|
                map(attribute='hname')|
                map('community.general.counter')|
                map(attribute='/')|
                map('community.general.dict_kv', 'counter') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  counters:
  - counter: 1
  - counter: 2
  - counter: 3
  - counter: 3
  - counter: 2
```

Combine the items of *counters* and *id_hname_type* and sort the list by *counter*

```yaml
  ids: "{{ id_hname_type|
           zip(counters)|
           map('combine')|
           sort(attribute='counter', reverse=true) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  ids:
    - counter: 3
      hname: Global/NETWORK/DATA CENTERS/PRIMARY DC
      id: d8cf28e4-5955-4221-a6ba-b8c2c2a49647
      type: [area]
    - counter: 3
      hname: Global/NETWORK/BRANCH SITES/NORTH EAST
      id: c6843603-ab6f-4afb-9258-0f3d0f09b804
      type: [area]
    - counter: 2
      hname: Global/NETWORK/DATA CENTERS
      id: 426e3c41-3245-4c5a-b742-e567ab3b7cff
      type: [area]
    - counter: 2
      hname: Global/NETWORK/BRANCH SITES
      id: 493381e5-9d71-42df-b3d5-79eefbf5b07f
      type: [area]
    - counter: 1
      hname: Global/NETWORK
      id: 24db7872-91bf-4890-b535-92d069b7595
      type: [area]
```

Answer (score 0):

```yaml
---
- name: Test
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    id_hname_type:
      - hname: "Global/NETWORK"
        id: "24db7872-91bf-4890-b535-92d069b75950"
        type:
          - "area"
      - hname: "Global/FCMB NETWORK/DATA CENTERS/PRIMARY DC"
        id: "d8cf28e4-5955-4221-a6ba-b8c2c2a49647"
        type:
          - "area"
      - hname: "Global/NETWORK/DATA CENTERS"
        id: "426e3c41-3245-4c5a-b742-e567ab3b7cff"
        type:
          - "area"
      - hname: "Global/NETWORK/BRANCH SITES"
        id: "493381e5-9d71-42df-b3d5-79eefbf5b07f"
        type:
          - "area"
      - hname: "Global/FCMB NETWORK/BRANCH SITES/NORTH EAST"
        id: "c6843603-ab6f-4afb-9258-0f3d0f09b804"
        type:
          - "area"
  tasks:
    - name: Initialize an empty list for the new variable
      # This task initializes a new list that will hold the updated dictionaries
      set_fact:
        new_id_hname_type: []

    - name: Add length attribute and slash count
      # This task adds 'hname_length' and 'slash_count' attributes to each dictionary in the list
      set_fact:
        new_id_hname_type: "{{ new_id_hname_type + [dict(item, hname_length=(item.hname | length), slash_count=((item.hname | split('/')) | length - 1))] }}"
      loop: "{{ id_hname_type }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.hname }}"

    - name: Set the new variable
      # This task replaces the original list with the updated one
      set_fact:
        id_hname_type: "{{ new_id_hname_type }}"

    - name: Sort by hname_length and slash_count in descending order
      # This task sorts the list first by 'hname_length' and then by 'slash_count', both in descending order
      set_fact:
        id_hname_type: "{{ id_hname_type | sort(attribute='hname_length', reverse=True) | sort(attribute='slash_count', reverse=True) }}"
      
    - name: Initialize a list for final result
      # This task initializes a new list for the final result
      set_fact:
        final_id_hname_type: []

    - name: Remove hname_length and slash_count attributes
      # This task iterates over each dictionary in the list and creates a new dictionary without 'hname_length' and 'slash_count', and adds it to the final list
      set_fact:
        final_id_hname_type: "{{ final_id_hname_type + [{'hname': item.hname, 'id': item.id, 'type': item.type}] }}"
      loop: "{{ id_hname_type }}"
      
    - name: Show result
      # This task prints the final list
      debug: 
        var: final_id_hname_type
```

Result:

```yaml
TASK [Show result] *********************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "final_id_hname_type": [
        {
            "hname": "Global/FCMB NETWORK/DATA CENTERS/PRIMARY DC",
            "id": "d8cf28e4-5955-4221-a6ba-b8c2c2a49647",
            "type": [
                "area"
            ]
        },
        {
            "hname": "Global/FCMB NETWORK/BRANCH SITES/NORTH EAST",
            "id": "c6843603-ab6f-4afb-9258-0f3d0f09b804",
            "type": [
                "area"
            ]
        },
        {
            "hname": "Global/NETWORK/DATA CENTERS",
            "id": "426e3c41-3245-4c5a-b742-e567ab3b7cff",
            "type": [
                "area"
            ]
        },
        {
            "hname": "Global/NETWORK/BRANCH SITES",
            "id": "493381e5-9d71-42df-b3d5-79eefbf5b07f",
            "type": [
                "area"
            ]
        },
        {
            "hname": "Global/NETWORK",
            "id": "24db7872-91bf-4890-b535-92d069b75950",
            "type": [
                "area"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other way I found was also useful and would keep playbook short was creating a [Custom Filter Plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#filter-plugins) in Python like the following **`custom_filters.py`**

```python
def count_slashes_and_sort_by_attribute(items, attribute):
    def get_slash_count(item):
        return item.get(attribute, '').count('/')

    return sorted(items, key=get_slash_count, reverse=True)

class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'count_slashes_and_sort_by_attribute': count_slashes_and_sort_by_attribute,            
        }
```

And then create task like:

```yaml
- name: Sort the id_hname_type list based on the number of slashes in hname attribute
  set_fact:
    sorted_id_hname_type: "{{ id_hname_type | count_slashes_and_sort_by_attribute('hname') }}"
```